# REDIS php extension connect error

Tags: php, redis

When I use redis PHP extension, I get the error, the host is 127.0.0.1 and the port is 6379.

> Redis::connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known.

Comment: are you sure your redis is running on port 6379?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue happening sporadically on my local server with a number of attempted fixes yielding no resolution. [This post here](http://albertech.net/2011/05/fix-php_network_getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-known/) gave me an idea that seems to have finally fixed the problem.

Basically, I have a number of vhosts set up on my local machine (running Ubuntu) which allows me to use domain names to access locally-run sites instead of the usual 'localhost/sitename' approach. As a result, I had no IP assigned to 'localhost' name.

This might not be the same root cause for the problem for you, but here's how I've solved mine:

1. See what is the value of 'redis-host' in your redis config file
   (for me it's set to 'localhost').
2. In your /etc/hosts file check
   that there's an IP assigned to that host name. (In your case, where
   redis-host is 127.0.0.1, check that there isn't some other host name
   assigned to that IP, like phpmyadmin, for example.)

Of course, as a sanity check, make sure your redis-server is up and running, try rebooting Apache in case you've made any config changes, etc.

Answer (score 5):

For mac users:

Open terminal and try this command:

1. sudo vi /etc/hosts 
   (sudo to execute the command as a root user,
   You have enter the password for this)
2. press 'i' to get into input mode of VI editor
3. Add this line at the end     **127.0.0.1 redis**
4. press esc to go to command mode
5. type :wq (to save and quit the vi
   editor)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was simple; the host name was incorrectly typed.

To find out the exact issue, I had to do the following in my console:

```
ping <host-name>
```

or if you have redis-cli installed, you can just call that from the console as such:

```
redis-cli -h <host-name> -p <port-number> -a <auth-pass>
```

[Source](http://albertech.net/2011/05/fix-php_network_getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-known/)